# Unix: fork and wait

Tags: shell, command, history

Here is the last part I do not understand in the source code of the command if.

Source: http://v6shell.org/history/if.c, with Syntax-Highlighting: http://pastebin.com/bj0Hvfrw

```
if(eq(a, "{")) { /* execute a command for exit code */
    if(fork()) /*parent*/ wait(&ccode);
    else { /*child*/
        doex(1);
        goto err;
    }
    while((a=nxtarg()) && (!eq(a,"}")));
    return(ccode? 0 : 1);
}
```

As described in the man-page (http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/if), if we put the command in brackets "*if expr { command }* ", we can obtain his exit code.

So we fork the current process, and then wait for our child process to finish? But where is our child process continuing his work? After the fork, we will go into the while-loop and and just skip some arguments and then return with ccode? Where was ccode changed? What is ccode?

**Could you please explain me this the given code snippet? 
And elaborate on ccode?**

The man page of wait: http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/wait

Comment: Please ask your questions about C programming on [so], not here. Programming questions are off-topic here, even if they're about Unix programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) splits the current process in two: [it makes a new process, running the same code, which begins running from the same point as the `fork` call](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/fork). `fork` returns a different value in the parent and the child: in the parent, it returns the PID of the child process, and in the child it returns zero. The PID is a true value, so the `wait` call only executes in the parent (as the comment says), and the "`else`" branch only executes in the child (as its comment says). Both processes execute in parallel from the point of the `fork` onwards.

[`doex` performs an `exec` of another program, replacing the child process and terminating with the new process's exit code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177287/why-does-execv-exit-a-function). Only the `doex` call and `execv` execute in the child process from the current program.

[`wait`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/wait):

> causes its caller to delay until one of its child processes terminates.

That is, it causes the parent to pause until the child has exited. It is passed a pointer to an `int` variable and writes exit information for the child process into that variable. `ccode` is defined elsewhere in the enclosing function. The child process's exit code will be the exit code of the command that was `exec`ed.

When `ccode` has been given a non-zero value, that indicates an error running the program. In that case, the function returns zero, and otherwise it returns 1 to indicate success to its caller.

---

I encourage you take a look at either [POSIX/the Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/mindex.html), the ISO C standard, or a standard C programming textbook to help understand what's going on in this codebase. The man pages that you link to also describe what the functions do, but often the newer versions fill in the gaps or are generally clearer, and the behaviour hasn't changed too much.

Although all of these questions are related to historical Unix, and the interplay between Unix and C at that point combined with the subsequent changes to both in the intervening time makes them arguably on-topic, they're also rudimentary programming questions (and so arguably off-topic).

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for this detailed great answer! :)